# Construct homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology

**Definition**

> $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is called a homeomorphism if :
>
> (a) $f$ is continuous on $X$
>
> (b) $f$ is one to one and onto
>
> (c) $f^{-1} : Y \rightarrow X$ is continuous on $Y$

Then how to construct homeomorphisms $f$ :

(a) $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ where $[a,b],[c,d]$ are closed intervals of $E^1$

(b) $f:(a,b) \rightarrow E^1$

(c) $f:S^3-N \rightarrow E^3$ where $N=(1,0,0,0)$ is the north pole of $S^3$ ( $S$ means sphere)

> My attempt :
>
> (a) Consider $X=[-1,1]$ and $Y=[0,5]$
>
> let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be $f(x)= \frac {5}{2} (x+1)$.
>
> Observe that $f$ is bijective and continuous, being the compositions of addition and multipliction. Moreover, $f^{-1}$ exists and is continuous :
>
> $f^{-1}(x)=\frac {2}{5}x -1$
>
> Note that neiher $[0,1]$ nor $[0,1)$ is homeomorphic as such mapping between these intervals, if constructed, will fail to a bijection due endpoints.
>
> (b) Let $X=(-1,1)$ and $Y=E^1$.
>
> The general open set $(a,b)$ is homeomorphic to $(-1,1)$.
>
> Now define a continuous map $f:(-1,1) \rightarrow E^1$ by
>
> $f(x)=tan \frac{\pi x}{2}$
>
> This continuous bijection possesses a continuous inverse $f^{-1}:E^1 \rightarrow (-1,1)$ by
>
> $f^{-1}(x)= \frac {2}{\pi}arc tan (x)$
>
> Hence $f:(-1,1) \rightarrow E^1$ is a homeomorphism

I changed my question by adding an attempt to my question.

Answer (score 0):

(a) think linear functions.

(b) think about stuff like $\frac{1}{x}$ or $\tan(x)$

(c) Google "stereographic projection"

Comment: can you explain or give an example for question (a) ?

Comment: @user326307 write down the formula for the unique linear function that sends $a$ to $c$ and $b$ to $d$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/812353)

Comment: @TheCount I gave three (correct) hints. I'm not spelling out the complete answer all the time.

Comment: This came up on my review queue and I reviewed it as I felt was best. You may disagree and that's okay.